# Injecting script code in head

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

I'm trying to inject the script code as child of document.head using my Firefox's addon.

*\chrome\content\test.js:*

```
function test() {
    var injTest = document.createElement('script');
        injTest.innerHTML = ["alert('test')"].join('\n');
    (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(injTest);
}
test();
```

But it doesn't work. What else do i need to do?

In Chrome extension it works:

*manifest "content_scripts":*

```
  ///
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://example.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.11.3.min.js", "content_script.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  ///
```

*content_script:*

```
function test() {
    var injTest = document.createElement('script');
        injTest.innerHTML = ["alert('test')"].join('\n');
    (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(injTest);
}
test();
```

Comment: If you add a console.log in the test function, does it show up? I say that to see if it's Firefox now allowing you to inject code (without proper authorization for your extension) or if it's not even calling the code.

Comment: Is this a bootstrap addon? or an sdk addon? In bootstrap you have to set `contentaccessible=true` in the chrome.manifest as seen here: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9406437#file-chrome-manifest-L1 although I would not recommend this method. Its easiest to set up a sandbox and run code straight from the addon as seen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.Sandbox#Executing_in_current_tab_scope

Comment: @Noitidart I don't use sdk. I have in my chrome.manifest `contentaccessible=yes`

Comment: You have to create a file in then set src to that file, you cant do inline with `contentaccessbiel`, that hsould fix it then, however I still recommend sandbox method.

Comment: Can you jump onto irc i can talk you through it https://client00.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%extdev

Comment: I solved the problem. I used next: `e.originalTarget;` & `try...catch`. I've put `var... e.originalTarget.createElement('script');...` into `try..catch` and it works. Function starts when DOMContentLoaded: `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) { test.InjScript(e); }, true);`